# NUnit3 test adapter warnings on azure pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, nunit, vstest, dotnet-test

recently without any direct changes to tests solution this error started occurring during execution of VSTEST@2 task on my azure pipeline.

```
##[warning]DiscoveryMessage : Failed to load extensions from file 'D:\a\1\s\src\...\NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll'. Please use /diag for more information.
```

It isn't breaking tests discovery or execuction phase but it trashes my warning dialog and might make me omit some more important warnings. Have any of you faced similar problem so far? Tried to look for such error for some time now and couldn't find any solution.

Also I thought that maybe my vstest task tries to discover tests from TestAdapter but it shouldn't be the case with excluding clauses in definition

```
  - task: VSTest@2
    inputs:
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: |
                    **\*.Tests.dll
                    !**\*TestAdapter.dll
                    !**\NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll
                    !**\obj\**
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      distributionBatchType: basedOnExecutionTime
      codeCoverageEnabled: true
```

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this, I am facing the same issue

Comment: Couldn't find much more time to work on this but after quite some time I could correlate this with some packages update however didnt fix it yet. If you get to know anything more please let me know as well:) @coder

Comment: I hate to just "bump," but I'm curious if you ever resolved this? We're experiencing it as well and your question here seems to be the only info about it anywhere...

Comment: Unfortunately this stuff keeps bothering me, didn't find enough time to dig further.